# What are the advantages of ES5 over ES3?

Tags: ecmascript-5

Maybe it's a basic question, but what differences are there between:
- a web project developped with ES3 support and
- a web project developped with ES5 support?

In other words, what enhancements can you add to your projects if you support ES5 ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's probably hard to list here all things that are new in ES5, but the ones that may be helpful in your case are mostly related to language improvements. Some of the key points:

- Methods for searching and manipulating array contents: indexOf, map, filter, reduce, forEach, etc.
- Standard of representation for dates as strings (ISO 8601).
- Functions for converting objects to and from JSON
- 'use strict' - strict mode changes some JavaScript silent errors to throw errors, fixes some Javascript mistakes to enable better optimisation and so on.

Switching to ES5 can probably speed up your development process a bit and can help make your code robust and optimised.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. Do you any links that I could read about it ?

Comment: There's a very good presentation by Doug Crockford on "Ecmascript 5, The New Parts": [watch it on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTEqr0IlFKY)